# Strategies to Track, Maintain multiple variations/ flavors of Sales/ Marketing Word Documents with cross pollination?

Tags: version-control, ms-word, branching-and-merging

Strategies to Track, Maintain multiple variations/ flavors of Sales/ Marketing Word Documents with cross pollination?

- I've been reading interesting examples of people using Tortoise, Plastic SCM, Magnet SVN, Mercurial etc for maintaining word documents as well (with/ without various plugins etc.)
- I've read some basic info on SVN, Git, Hg etc.
- I have a technical background but I'd like to ask this from the Point of View of a Writer/ User. Now the question is not so much technical, but more so 'capability' based.
- At the moment, it will be a single user handling these variations/ flavors (myself).

Direction:

- I will be starting from a Master Word Document (Product & Services Sales/ Marketing Proposals).
- The eventual goal may not be a single Master Word Document but various independent variations/ flavors that this existing Word Document would take & maintain.
- There will be "custom" variations which may remain separate forever (for marketing & presenting to different people)
- Some updates, elements & data from these flavors/ variations could sometimes be "shared" and "merged" with each other and certain parts could remain Separate & Distinct for good.
- **There is no eventual goal to Converge into a Single Flavor/ Variation.**
- **These are being customized to appeal to varying customers and clients but would love to have some way to interpolate/ cross-pollinate the improvements over time.**

QUESTION:

- **Are these version control systems CAPABLE of managing/ handling such "long term" flavors/ variations with Cross-Pollination for these sales/ marketing documents?**
- **If yes, then please suggest some 'strategies' on executing these many flavors/ variations? I've read 'branch, trunk, tags, clone' in relation to Code. 
  What would be good strategies/ execution ideas here?**

Thanks in advance. Please do advise.

PS: Of course, Visual diff & Interpolating/ Merging parts of Word Documents would happen often.

Comment: @Lazy Badger - There may be refinement of some Masters but given that these are sales/ marketing proposals & documents there is no saying that latter versions will always be better than former versions. What will dictate most appropriate size & content? The certain client scenario. 

I just need to be able to go back & forth and side ways and maybe diagonals sometimes and cross pollinate data as and when needed. 

Visual Merging between various versions of Word Documents is going to be a pain to some extent but it is acceptable. 

Being able to have PATHS across time & variations will be key

Answer (score 1):

Well, from my POV, your task can be easy powered by any existing SCM (most headache will go from ugly MS-side, not VCS).

AFAICS, your history will be strictly linear, thus - you can don't worry about "better|worse merging" (in any case merging Word-files is terrible nightmare).

I think, you imagine you workflow slightly incorrect (as I see your task): at some stage you'll have **a set of**:
* Master Documents
* (different) files , different combination of which are included in different Masters as Subdocuments

All Masters and Subs are versioned and, therefore, changes are tracked. Reordering of parts in Master and|or adding|deleting|editing Subs files change final **business-documents**

Comment: There may be refinement of some Masters but given that these are sales/ marketing proposals & documents there is no saying that latter versions will always be better than former versions. What will dictate most appropriate size & content? The certain client scenario. 

I just need to be able to go back & forth and side ways and maybe diagonals sometimes and cross pollinate data as and when needed. 

Visual Merging between various versions of Word Documents is going to be a pain to some extent but it is acceptable. 

Being able to have PATHS across time & variations will be key

Answer (score 1):

For Word documents, you are probably better off looking at document management systems than SCM systems.

For example, in the Java world, alfresco, eXo, nuxeo etc.  I wouldn't call it light, but you can run alfresco on a laptop.

Some DMS provide special support for content re-use.

If you weren't working in Word, you could use an XML component management system.  See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyDITA or http://www.componize.com/

In fact, you can use that sort of approach. You could shred your Word docx (ie unzip it, and then split out the re-usable chunks) into eXist or MarkLogic. These systems can dynamically re-assemble the document when someone wants to view them in Word. The re-usable chunks could be versioned separately. And you could have an interface for re-combining to create new documents. The pieces are there, but you'd need to do some (not inconsiderable) development yourself to create a complete system.

Some links to get you thinking (Google "component management" ECM OR document):

- http://www.cmprofessionals.org/index.cfm?fuseaction=Feature.showFeature&featureID=41
- www.single-source-forum.de/rueckblicke/2005/folien/ssf05_folien_kuppers.pdf
- http://www.component-management.com/

Another approach entirely would be to look at document assembly systems. Some of these support components (content re-use). Document assembly systems also enable you to have a single 'smart' template, which contains all the variations, instead of multiple documents.

If you Google 'document assembly', you'll see systems which are available at all price points (from free, to v expensive).  See further http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_automation and http://www.americanbar.org/publications/law_practice_today_home/law_practice_today_archive/september12/magic-in-minutes.html

Comment: *(1) What kind of document management systems are you talking about? I am guessing these would be heavey/ large ones and not something that is light and can be run on a Local Machine/ Laptop. 
*(2) When you talk about Document Assembly are you pointing towards XML based Schemas like DocBook etc? Eventually I might consider going in that direction

Comment: Thanks Jason. I forgot how Law Firms need to assemble and maintain legal documentation and recompose pieces. I'd like to do something similar but without running something massive - something running on my laptop / local machine more client-side oriented. 
I did go through some of your suggestions and googled for more. I might have to take deeper dive & evaluate some of them and see what fits the bill and then report back.

Comment: I've added a paragraph sketching out an approach for using eXist or MarkLogic XML databases.  I've done some of this recently, and some years back. Anyway, will be interested in your report back.

Comment: Hey Jason - Thank you so much. I've been playing with some things but haven't figured out a conclusive choice here. I was just wondering if you had any updated thoughts/ ideas? 

PS: Would the MarkLogic/ eXist option still work? Seems like the are NoSQL DBs now?

Comment: Well I think your main decision point is whether your atomic unit of content is the document itself, or some "chunk of content" (group of contiguous paragraphs/tables/images) which you want to re-use across various documents.  The second approach is more complex to set up, so probably only warranted if you'll benefit sufficiently from the re-use.  eXist hasn't changed; it is still an XML database.  The rest is marketing :-)

Comment: Chunks of Content that need to get assembled into documents as and when needed. The most convenient way to do it on a laptop/ desktop/ web wins. Would this be better posted on some StackExchange site where I can ask Law firm related people on 'Document Assembly' systems?

Comment: Or on a DITA forum.  SO itself frowns upon long discussions like this!